# System.MissingFieldException while sending email using ECM

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-ecm

I am trying to configure ECM for newsletter campaign. (Sitecore 6.6, ECM 1.3 - update any of those is not an option)

There is an issue, when I try to send message it sticks in Processing folder and is never moved to Sent folder.

In the logs I can see there is an exception System.MissingFieldException and the field (note this is not a Sitecore field but a field in a class) which is missing is FieldIDs.TrafficType. FieldIDs is a static class defined in a Sitecore.Analytics assembly.

```
ManagedPoolThread #8 10:11:42 ERROR EmailCampaign: Field not found: 'FieldIDs.TrafficType'.
Exception: System.MissingFieldException
Message: Field not found: 'FieldIDs.TrafficType'.
Source: Sitecore.EmailCampaign
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Pipelines.DispatchNewsletter.DeployAnalytics.AddCampaignItem(MessageItem message)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Pipelines.DispatchNewsletter.DeployAnalytics.ProcessCampaign(MessageItem message)
   at Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Pipelines.DispatchNewsletter.DeployAnalytics.Process(DispatchNewsletterArgs args)
```

When I decompile this class with reflector and try to see value of this field I get an exception saying that "The memeber is not loadaed or may be hidden due to your visibility settings." It looks as if this field was defined in some different assmebly which I did not include.

I tried turning off the processor responsible for creation of the campaign (the exception is thrown in this processor) since I do not need analytics for my newsletter and it partially helped - the message was moved to Sent folder. But it was never sent to the recipients, since there was no campaing created and now the exception is thrown in the other phase of sending.

I will appreciate any help or suggestion on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I knew this would happen. I struggled with this for a while and manage to resolve the problem couple of minutes after posting here...

Anyway.

The problem was with incorrect Sitecore.EmailCampaign asemmbly which was used in the project previously. Someone must have added it and it was not used for a long time. When I installed clean version of the Sitecore I am working on and then Sitecore ECM, sending emails worked as a charm. So I compared libraries in both websites and updated those which were different and surprisingly the emails are now sent without any issue.

Previously I was using Sitecore.EmailCampaign version 1.3.1 and now I have updated to Sitecore.EmailCampaign version 1.3.3. Also I have update all dlls EmailCampaign depends on.

Pretty specific issue but maybe this question will help someone.